# is there a way to generate a pom.xml with dependencies from an eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependency-management

I have inherited a big project with several subprojects.
all of them use several jar files, all of them located under each project's lib directory. I want to take all the projects and migrate them to maven, but dependencies are a problem (too many of them), some of them are commonly used libraries (apache projects, xerces, jms, etc) and others are not.

is there a way to autogenerate maven dependencies for those jars that can be found on public maven repositories. for example, see that my project use the spice-jndikit-1.2.jar file and automatically get the appropiate depedency with group, artifact and (if possible) version?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a groovy script to generate a starting set of [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) files.

https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy

In my case, I wanted to "Maven-ize" my ANT builds without switching completely away from ANT.
It is feasible to extend this code to generate a Maven POM, if people were interested in this feature.

Comment: You know this is quite good. Combined with the API guide that the search service provides (http://search.maven.org/#api), you can get most of the way there, if not at least get you a list to quickly check against.

Comment: @SpencerKormos Agreed, that was the purpose in writing the script. In practice, I find it identifies approx 80% of a project's jar files. The ones that don't match are generally either closed source software or repackaged open source jars. Finally, you recommend the new Maven Central search REST API. This is provided by the same people who host "repository.sonatype.org". Clearly my script could switch, but I'd prefer to maintain compatibility with Nexus. Hosting commercial jars in a private instance of Nexus enables my script to find these as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a project to Maven using the m2e plugin, but this erases your jar references, and should not be used.

I doubt that such a thing exists since typical jars (unless themselves built with Maven) don't have the necessary information to correlate the groupId, artifactId and version back to a repository to get the proper path.

You might be able to write something that parses the file name for the name and version, but you still have the package-based path to figure out.

Comment: yes, I was afraid of that. it is a shame jars don't contain extra information.

Comment: Check Mark's entry above. Combined with the maven.org search API, it can get most of the way there I think.

Comment: I have a need for this as well, and it doesn't seem like a major project to write something that gets you most of the way there, and issues warnings for what's missing.   If I start a github project, I'll let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building using Ant, you might also consider using Apache Ivy, and its file-system based resolution (very fast and easy to configure), to get you started, and slowly role over to the Maven repos for the artifacts, this way you're not spending a lot of time up-front finding Maven dependencies.